# Iterate through values with underscore.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a template like this:

```
template: _.template('<% if (inputType == "select") {%><select id="<%= id %>" class="<%= contentClass %>" name="<%= name %>">....options should go here! </select><%}%></p>'),
```

In my model, one of the attributes is an array. Imagine the object I am working with looks something like this:

```
"contentType":"input",
"contentClass":"createProject_cat",
"placeholder":"Project Category",
"name":"createProject_cat",
"inputType":"select",
"id":"3",
"value":["1","2","3"]
```

In this example, I am looking to wrap `1, 2 and 3` from the `value` attribute in `<option>` tags and then output them between the two `<select>` tags from the template above.

I would like to wrap each of the values in the child array with an `option` tag and output in the above template. Is there a simple way to iterate through these values printing and outputting them from within the template?

Answer (score 4):

You can do the same as the if condition :

```
<% for(var i=0; i<value.length; i++) { %>
    <option value="<%= value[i] %>">
<% } %>
```